# Isolate $z$ in equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

This is an equation to find the field strength of a cylindrical magnet at a given distance. I'd like to reverse it and find a distance for a given field strength along the polar axis.

z is length

D is thickness

R is radius

h is remanence field

b is field strength in teslas

Can someone walk me through the steps to isolate z from this equation?

$$ b = \frac{h}{2} \left(\frac{D+z}{\sqrt{(D+z)^2+R^2}}-\frac{z}{\sqrt{ R^2+z^2}}\right) $$

I have a known b,h,D,R but I have an unknown z

example with numbers.

$$ 0.008801 = \frac{1.48}{2} \left(\frac{0.09375+0.438}{\sqrt{(0.09375+0.438)^2+0.125^2}}-\frac{0.438}{\sqrt{ 0.125^2+0.438^2}}\right) $$

Edit: I edited my equation. Sorry I messed it up when converting to mark up.

[Equation is from this website](http://www.supermagnete.de/eng/faq/How-do-you-calculate-the-magnetic-flux-density)

Comment: i think it is not so easy, from where do you got this problem?

Comment: you will get a polynomial in degree $8$! How will you solve this for $z$?

Comment: Equation in the title looks different (parentheses) compared to that in the body.

Comment: how is the equation exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I screwed up my equation. I fixed it and gave a link to the source.

Comment: now it is the same a polynomial of degree $8$ do you have an example with numbers?

Comment: Yes it might be a bit, but I'll add an example.

Comment: Example with numbers added.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your example but the term at the left (b) is numerically near $0.00877522619$ (with this value of $b$ the method proposed returns indeed $0.438$ starting with the value $A=0.00883609$ returned by [alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%28%28%280.09375%2F0.25%29%5E2%2Ba%5E2%29%5E2%3D%281.48%2F0.00877522619%29%5E2*a%5E3*%281%2Ba%29%29)).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Sorry I accidentally copied the wrong answer from my spread sheet. Again sorry. I fixed it.

Comment: This value of $b$ is fine and the resulting solution using $$z=R\left(\sqrt{C^2-1}\sqrt{1+A}-C\sqrt{A}\right)$$ with $\;C:=\cosh(t)=\dfrac{D}{2R\,\sqrt{A}}\;$ is indeed $z\approx 0.4375$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that $\;z=R\,\sinh(t-a)\,$ and $\;D+z=R\,\sinh(t+a)\;$ then
\begin{align}
\frac{2b}h&= \frac{D+z}{\sqrt{(D+z)^2+R^2}}-\frac{z}{\sqrt{ R^2+z^2}}\\
&=\tanh(t+a)-\tanh(t-a)\\
&=\frac{\sinh(t+a)}{\cosh(t+a)}-\frac{\sinh(t-a)}{\cosh(t-a)}\\
&=\frac{\sinh((t+a)-(t-a))}{(\cosh(t)\cosh(a))^2-(\sinh(t)\sinh(a))^2}\\
&=\frac{\sinh(2a)}{\cosh(t)^2+\cosh(a)^2-1}\\
\end{align}
That we will rewrite as :
$$\tag{1}\cosh(t)^2+\sinh(a)^2=\frac{h\,\sinh(2a)}{2b}$$
We have too $\;D=R\,(\sinh(t+a)-\sinh(t-a))\;$ so that 
$$\tag{2}D=2\,R\,\cosh(t)\sinh(a)$$
Let's note $A:=\sinh(a)^2\,$ and use the expression of $\;\cosh(t)$ from $(2)$ :
$$\tag{3}\cosh(t)=\frac{D}{2R\,\sqrt{A}}$$
and replace it in $(1)$ to get :
$$\frac {D^2}{4R^2\,A}+A=\frac{h\,\sinh(a)\sqrt{1+\sinh(a)^2}}{b}=\frac{h\sqrt{A(1+A)}}{b}$$
Multiplying by $\,A$ and squaring we get :
$$\tag{4}\left(\frac {D^2}{4R^2}+A^2\right)^2=\left(\frac hb\right)^2\,A^3(1+A)$$
Solving the [quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) you may

- obtain $A$ (the smallest positive real solution when it exists I think)
- deduce $t$ (or rather use directely $\cosh(t)$)
- and finally obtain the wished $z$.

  This is not really straightforward but could be the wished solution (all this should be verified of course).

Comment: ok so I'm not understanding where where you got $z=Rsinh(t−a)$ and $D+z=Rsinh(t+a)$

Comment: And if $A = sinh(a)^2$ how do I find $a$ and also how do I find $t$?

Comment: @TheColonel26: First question : I am rewriting $z$ as a function of two new variables $t$ and $a$ (this can always be done from the [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#/media/File:Sinh_cosh_tanh.svg) of $\sinh$). This was done to simplify the term at the right as $\tanh(t+a)-\tanh(t-a)$. Second question : $(4)$ is a quartic you'll have to solve it first (follow the 'quartic' link from the answer for the method). I used [alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%28%28%280.09375%2F0.25%29%5E2%2Ba%5E2%29%5E2%3D%281.48%2F0.00877522619%29%5E2%2Aa%5E3%2A%281%2Ba%29%29)

Comment: in the example provided (in the comments under your question) to get $A$, I didn't evaluate $t$ (nor $a$ in fact) but $\;C:=\cosh(t)=\dfrac{D}{2R\,\sqrt{A}}\;$ and deduced the value of $z$ using $$z=R\left(\sqrt{C^2-1}\sqrt{1+A}-C\sqrt{A}\right)$$ as indicated (from the expansion of $\;z=R\,\sinh(t-a)\,$).  The difficult part is the resolution of the quartic. Hoping this clarified things,

Comment: Ooooh I get it now, thank you

Comment: Glad it clarified @TheColonel26. Excellent continuation,